# On the element order of $GL(2,q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a element of this type
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & a \\
1 & b \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
with order $2(q-1)$ in $GL(2,q)$, where **$q$ is an odd prime**? If exists, can we calculate $b$?

My main problem is find all such $a$ and $b$.

Comment: How do you get $a = \pm 1$? You can take $b=0$ and $a$ a primitive element of ${\mathbb F}_q$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake and giving one solution. Yes, you are right. I made a mistake. I can't get $a=1$ or $-1$. Can we find all $a$ and $b$ such that this matrix has order $2(q-1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Derek's comment already solved this: take $\;b=0\;,\;\;a\;$ a primitive element in $\;\Bbb F_q\;$ , so that:

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\implies A^2=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}\implies A^{2(q-1)}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. But is this the only matrix of this type with order $2(q-1)$? How about the others? Can we calculate all of them?

Comment: Yes all elements of order $\lambda(q-1)$ for $\lambda > 1$ are powers of a Singer cycle, and they square into a scalar matrix. They all have trace $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what singer cycle is. Can you show me how to calculate? Thanks. @Derek Holt.

Comment: A Singer cycle is an element of order $q^2-1$ that can described as multiplication by a primitive element in the field of order $q^2$.

Comment: After your explaining Singer cycle, I tried to figure out what you said about that matrix. I still don't know how to prove your answer. Could you explain more specificly? @Derek Holt

Comment: The eigenvalues of an element of order $2(q-1)$ lie in ${\mathbb F}_{q^2} \setminus {\mathbb F}_q$. So the cyclic subgroup it generates acts irreducibly but not absolutely irreducibly, with splitting field ${\mathbb F}_{q^2} $. So, over ${\mathbb F}_{q^2}$, it is similar to the diagonal matrix with entries $w,w^q$, where $w$ has order $2(q-1)$. Its square is the scalar matrix $\lambda I_2$ where $\lambda$ is a primitive element of ${\mathbb F}_q$. So its minimal polynomial is $x^2-\lambda$ and hence, it has trace $0$. So $b=0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36991/discussion-between-user44312-and-derek-holt).